# Can't change minimum laser range with asus xtion pro

Tags: ros, laser, asus-xtion-pro, depthimage-to-laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using an asus xtion pro camera with a turtlebot 2 and I noticed that it only registers scans that are at least 0.45 meters away even though the edge of the robot is around 0.3 meters.  I changed the parameter value for "/depthimage_to_laserscan/range_min" to 0.2 but this has no effect on how close it detects obstacles.

How can I change the minimum laser range?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230691/can%27t-change-minimum-laser-range-with-asus-xtion-pro/) by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2016-03-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my experience, the **Asus Xtion Pro** itself has a **minimum range** of **0.5 meters** (actually the [official specifications](https://www.asus.com/3D-Sensor/Xtion_PRO_LIVE/specifications/) say the minimum range is 0.8 meters) so it is not a problem with the *depth_image_to_laserscan* parameters.

If you need to see obstacles closer than 0.5 meters away you will need a different sensor.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2016-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pgigioli](https://answers.ros.org/users/26279/pgigioli/) on 2016-04-01**:
Okay, I just verified this, thanks!  This is a huge hardware limitation especially for autonomous gmapping.